# How can i fix this error? I use Java Spring MVC thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

How can I fix it this error, I use java Spring-mvc thymeleaf, I want to move page from login page to tambah akun(sign up)page? but shows error

this is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "tb_akun")
public class Akun {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

This is my Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tambahakun/save")
public class TambahAkunController {

@Autowired
private TambahAkunRepository tambahAkunRepository;

@ModelAttribute("tambahakun")
private Akun getTambahAkun(@RequestParam(value="id",required = false)Long id )
{
    if(id==null)
        return new Akun();
    else
        return tambahAkunRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String form() {
    return "tambahakun";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("tambahakun") Akun tambahakun) {

    System.out.println(tambahakun.toString());
    tambahAkunRepository.save(tambahakun);

    return "redirect:/tambahakun";
}
```

}

This is My Html (tambahakun.html)

```
th:action="@{/tambahakun/save(id=${akun.id})}"method="post"th:object="${akun}">
```

This is my messages error

> 2019-07-17 11:49:33.409 ERROR 14064 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "akun.id" (template: "tambahakun" -
>   line 12, col 43)] with root cause
>
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:
>   Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

Comment: Is record exists in DB. As per this: return tambahAkunRepository.findById(id).orElse(null); it might be returning null and thats you are facing the issue.

Comment: The name of the model attribute you are using is tambahakun (@ModelAttribute("tambahakun")), so I think you should use ${tambahakun.id} and ${tambahakun}